# Kafka: How to consume data based on Timestamp

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I want know whether there's some way other than offset to fetch data with respect to time interval? Say, I want to consume all the date of yesterday, how do I do it?

Comment: Two-step process: Find the offset ranges that correspond to your date range and then consume those (by offset). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514167/retrieve-timestamp-based-data-from-kafka

Comment: @Thilo thanks for the comment, I did see that old thread and was wondering whether any change happened.. it means that I store offset details somewhere off the Kafka and based on that I query Kafka, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. Recent Kafka versions do include a timestamp on all messages. So no need for off-Kafka storage.

Comment: @Thilo can you please help me to find some example to access messages w.r.t timestamp? I am implementing in Python but Java example will work.. I could not find myself as yet.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Python API, but if you can access record metadata (offset, partition number) when you consume messages, then there should also be the timestamp.

Answer (score 14):

Use [offsetsForTimes](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/Consumer.html#offsetsForTimes(java.util.Map)) to get right offset related to the required timestamp. In Python it will be like next:

```
from datetime import datetime
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, TopicPartition

topic  = "www.kilskil.com" 
broker = "localhost:9092"

# lets check messages of the first day in New Year
date_in  = datetime(2019,1,1)
date_out = datetime(2019,1,2)

consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic, bootstrap_servers=broker, enable_auto_commit=True)
consumer.poll()  # we need to read message or call dumb poll before seeking the right position

tp      = TopicPartition(topic, 0) # partition n. 0
# in simple case without any special kafka configuration there is only one partition for each topic channel
# and it's number is 0

# in fact you asked about how to use 2 methods: offsets_for_times() and seek()
rec_in  = consumer.offsets_for_times({tp:date_in.timestamp() * 1000})
rec_out = consumer.offsets_for_times({tp:date_out.timestamp() * 1000})

consumer.seek(tp, rec_in[tp].offset) # lets go to the first message in New Year!

c = 0
for msg in consumer:
  if msg.offset >= rec_out[tp].offset:
    break

  c += 1
  # message also has .timestamp field

print("{c} messages between {_in} and {_out}".format(c=c, _in=str(date_in), _out=str(date_out)))
```

Don't forget that Kafka measures timestamp in milliseconds and it have **long** type. Python lib datetime return timestamps in seconds so we need to multiply it by 1000. Method `offsets_for_times` returns a dict with `TopicPartition` keys and `OffsetAndTimestamp` values.

Comment: Is there a way to handle date_out > latest offset timestamp scenario ? looks like it will fail now

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: To make it work I have needed add `consumer.assign([tp])`

Answer (score 3):

You can find the earliest offset for the beginning of the specified time interval and rewind to this offset. However, it is difficult to understand where the end of the interval is as the records with the earliest timestamps may arrive later. So you can consume the records from the start of the interval until you find the records with timestamps later than the endTime plus *some more* records to catch the late messages.

The code for the rewinding to the startTime is:

```
public void rewind(DateTime time) {
    Set<TopicPartition> assignments = consumer.assignment();
    Map<TopicPartition, Long> query = new HashMap<>();
    for (TopicPartition topicPartition : assignments) {
        query.put(topicPartition, time.getMillis());
    }
    Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndTimestamp> result = consumer.offsetsForTimes(query);

    result.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> consumer.seek(entry.getKey(),
            Optional.ofNullable(entry.getValue()).map(OffsetAndTimestamp::offset).orElse(new Long(0))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimalistic example in python with multiple partitions

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, TopicPartition
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

consumer = KafkaConsumer("test", bootstrap_servers="localhost:9092", group_id="group1", max_poll_records=5)
consumer.poll()
assignment = consumer.assignment()
date_in  = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=50)
date_out  = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=20)

for partition in assignment:
    rec_in  = consumer.offsets_for_times({partition:date_in.timestamp() * 1000})
    if(rec_in[partition] != None):
        consumer.seek(partition, rec_in[partition].offset)
        
for msg in consumer:
    if(msg.timestamp > date_out.timestamp()):
        print("pausing partiton=" + str(msg.partition))
        consumer.pause(TopicPartition("test2", msg.partition))
        if(len(consumer.paused()) == len(consumer.assignment())):
            break;
    print(msg)
```

Comment: I don't think consumer.paused() is a thing

Comment: the above code works on python for sure, i am not sure of other sdks.