# How can I query a Kafka topic to get all the records based on some criteria?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka topic that holds records in (timestamp, json) format. I am writing a spring boot application that needs to query the topic to get all the records available that are between two timestamps. Just for clarification.. I want to query the topic directly and not somehow save the records in a local storage after consuming those and query the storage. Can this be done using stream or any other method? If so, any code example would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39546012/3224238 if you have to check the values inside the records either you must read them all use http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#streamsapi to filter them

Comment: KSQL is another option, if you want to use that.